# Vue Watcher not working on component created with Vue.extend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a Parent component with a select input which is bound through v-model to a variable in data.

Besides, I create child components dynamically using Vue.extend, which i pass the propsData which also includes the value of the select.

This components have a watcher for the prop that is related to the select input.

When i create the component it receives the props succesfully, The problem comes when I update the value of the select input that doesn't trigger the watcher on the child component.

I've been looking for similar situations but have not found something that helps me solve this problem, i don't know why it doesn't trigger the watcher on the child component when the select input changes.

Any help would be very preciated.

Here i create the component dynamically:

```
let PresupuestoFormularioVue = Vue.extend(PresupuestoFormulario)
let instance = new PresupuestoFormularioVue({
  propsData: {
    //The prop related to select input  
    seguro: this.seguro,
  }
})
instance.$mount()
this.$refs.formularioContenedor.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

And this is the watcher in the component which isn't working:

```
watch:{
  seguro:{
    handler: function( newVal ){
      console.log(newVal)
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `watch` that doesn't work. It's the bindings. You're assigning the current value of `this.seguro`, not the reactive object itself. However, a `new Vue()` can add this binding for you.

As a sidenote, whether PresupuestoFormulario is a `Vue.extend()` doesn't matter. It can be any valid VueConstructor: a `Vue.extend()`, `Vue.component()` or a valid SFC (with name and template): `export default {...}`.

Here's how to do it:

```
methods: {
  addPresupuestoFormulario() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    this.$el.appendChild(div);
    new Vue({
      components: { PresupuestoFormulario },
      render: h => h("presupuesto-formulario", {
        props: {
          seguro: this.seguro
        }
      }) 
    }).$mount(div)
  }
}
```

The `<div>` initially appended to the parent will get replaced upon mounting with the actual template of `PresupuestoFormulario` and the bindings will be set, exactly as if you had `<presupuesto-formulario :seguro="seguro" />` in the parent template from the start.

The really cool part about it is that the parent component doesn't need to have `PresupuestoFormulario` declared in its `components`.

Here's a working example:

```js
const Test = Vue.component('test', {
  template: `<div>message: {{message}}</div>`,
  props: ['message'],
  watch: {
    message: console.log
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    msg: "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
  }),
  methods: {
    addComponent() {
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      this.$el.appendChild(div);
      new Vue({
        components: {
          Test
        },
        render: h => h("test", {
          props: {
            message: this.msg
          }
        })
      }).$mount(div);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="msg">
  <button @click="addComponent">Add dynamic child</button>
</div>
```

---

A separate note, about using `this.$el.appendChild()`. While this works when you're using a root Vue instance (a so-called Vue app), it will likely fail when using a normal Vue component, as Vue2 components are limited to having only 1 root element.
It's probably a good idea to have an empty container (e.g: `<div ref="container" />`) in the parent, and use `this.$refs.container.appendChild()` instead.

Comment: It never came to my mind that could be the binding the cause of the problem, and the fact that with new Vue() works sounds a bit odd to me. Thank you very much, it works effectively.

Comment: It's not odd at all. Every single component is a Vue instance. Whether you see it or not, `new Vue()` is, internally, called on every single Vue component instance. The only thing that's changed is that instead of having the parent call it, when it parses the template and finds the component, you call it yourself and then mount it into a `<div>` you added to the parent yourself. Because you want it to be dynamically added. Vue doesn't create apps. it creates components. Which can contain other components. We just call the top one App, as a convention.

Answer (score 2):

All of props that you want check in watcher, should be a function. If you want read more about this go to [vue document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) [codegrepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/vuejs+watcher+handler%28%29).

```
watch: {
    // whenever seguro changes, this function will run
    seguro: function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue,oldValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: As [documented](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch), a `watch` in Options API can be any function, a string matching a method name, or an options object, with `{ handler, immediate, deep }` interface.